# nginx configuration to map api calls to specific php modules

Tags: nginx

I am trying to build an nginx configuration for an Single Page Application that accesses PHP code through an API.  What I am trying to do is map an ajax call of the form `/api/xxx` through to a file in `project_directory/php/xxx.php`

So I have a location block like this:-

```
location ~* /api/(\w+) {
    root /path/to/project_directory;
    try_files /php/$1.php =404;
... call fastcgi gateway
}
```

I need to set up $fastcgi_script_name so that it will set all the correct environment variables.  Does it do this when try files matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ignore `$fastcgi_script_name` and replace any `fastcgi_param` directives with your re-mapped value. Your location block might start like:

```
location ~* /api/(\w+) {
  root /path/to/project_root;
  set $my_script_name /php/$1;
  try_files $my_script_name =404;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME     $my_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$my_script_name;
  ...
}
```

Obviously commenting out any conflicting `fastcgi_param` directives.